# Creating a job that converts view into a table on Snowflake

Tags: sql, datatables, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, scheduled-tasks

I want to create a job in the snowflake that converts my view into a table every day. I am new to snowflake so not sure how to do that.

Let's take the below code as an example view, but I am actually using a very complex view that takes a lot of time to compile, but I am able to convert the view into a table.

```
create or replace view example_db.example_schema.test_view as
select extract(day from sysdate()) as today, 
extract(day from sysdate()) - 1 as yesterday,
 extract(day from sysdate - 2) as day_before,
```

Situation: I want to convert the view I created above into a table. Below is the code for that

```
create table example_db.example_schema.test_table as
select * from example_db.example_schema.test_view
```

Now I want to create a job that refreshes this table above every day at 6 AM.

Question:

1. How to create a job in Snowflake, that will replace my table every day?
2. What happens when there is a new where clause in the original view example_db.example_schema.test_view, will the where clause impact my job that is creating the view into a table?
3. What happens when I insert a new column into my view example_db.example_schema.test_view shown above, will that impact the job that is converting the view into a table?

Most likely there won't be any new columns, just want to make sure of scenarios.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

you can write a Procedure, below is an example of a procedure which will read
a meta data table and move the data. This procedure is generalized to do the following

1. CXpy a Table to a View
2. Copy a table to a table
3. Copy View to a table
4. Copy View to a target view.

   **create or replace procedure DATA_TRANSFER_FF(p_src_db varchar2, p_tgt_db varchar2,  p_src_schema varchar2,  p_tgt_schema  varchar2,  p_src_obj_type varchar2,  p_tgt_obj_type varchar2 )**

   ```
                returns varchar(200)
                language sql
                as
                $$ declare
                  v_batch_id        integer;
                  v_log_sql_temp    varchar2;
                  v_log_sql         varchar2;
                  v_sql             varchar2(20000);
                  v_err_stmt        varchar2;   

                  v_sqlerrm         varchar2;
                  v_alter_stmt      varchar2;
                  table_exists      varchar2(1);  
                  v_modified        varchar2(100);
                  v_src_schema      varchar2(30);
                  v_tgt_schema      varchar2(30);

                  v_src_table       varchar2(30);
                  v_tgt_table       varchar2(30);

   -- The main cursor which loops thorough the list of tables.

    -- this is the table which stores the mapping for the source  and  target  table ,
   ```

--source and target schema.

```
                cur_main cursor for select source_table, target_table, source_schema, target_schema from COPY_TABLE_MAPPING   
     begin
         v_modified := '';
         v_alter_stmt := 'Before the cursor'; 
       
         -- Check the control table if the load has been completed.
         v_err_stmt := v_alter_stmt;
       
        
         open cur_main using ( );
         for i in cur_main do
            v_sql :='';   
            v_src_schema := :p_src_db || '.'|| :p_src_schema || '.';
            v_tgt_schema := :p_tgt_db || '.' || :p_tgt_schema || '.';
            v_src_table := i.source_table;
            v_tgt_table := i.target_table;
            
                 -- Different cases for  p_src_obj_type and p_tgt_obj_type      
             if ( (UPPER(p_src_obj_type) = 'VIEW') AND   (UPPER(p_tgt_obj_type) = 'TABLE')   ) THEN
                v_sql :='CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ' || v_tgt_schema || i.target_table || ' AS SELECT * FROM ' ||         v_src_schema ||  i.source_table;  
                v_err_stmt := v_sql;
              elseif ( (UPPER(p_src_obj_type) = 'TABLE') AND   (UPPER(p_tgt_obj_type) = 'TABLE')   ) THEN
                v_sql :='CREATE OR REPLACE ' || v_tgt_schema ||  i.target_table || '  CLONE ' ||  v_src_schema           || i.source_table; 
                v_err_stmt := v_sql;
              elseif ( ( (UPPER(p_src_obj_type) = 'TABLE') AND   (UPPER(p_tgt_obj_type) = 'VIEW')   )
                      OR ( (UPPER(p_src_obj_type) = 'VIEW') AND   (UPPER(p_tgt_obj_type) = 'VIEW')   ) ) THEN
                v_sql :='CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ' || v_tgt_schema || i.target_table || '  AS SELECT * FROM ' ||         v_src_schema ||  i.source_table;  
                v_err_stmt := v_sql;
               else
             return 'Nothing executed';
             end if;
          -- Grant the access to the ROLE as required  
            -- 12/05/2020 Before executing the Create view statement , will log it into a table
           v_log_sql := v_sql;
           select replace(replace(:v_log_sql, '\\', '\\\\'), '\'', '\\\'') into :v_log_sql_temp; 
        
        v_err_stmt := v_sql;
        execute immediate v_sql;
          end for;
    
         return 'Sucess';
          exception
            when other then
             return 'error';                
        end;
        $$;
```

Comment: Hi Himanshu, I will try this and update you. This works on Snowflake, right? I thought maybe we had to do tasks. Also wanted to know where we give the time input here, wanted it to be refreshed at 6 AM daily

Comment: HI , this is the procedure for Snowflake, it should work, if it is a View, it will always get the latest data what is in the Table, you will need to run it only one time. If the tables are a part of an ETL load and you want to see the data only when the load is complete you may have to modify this process, you may need to have a report staging schema where in the data during the ETL load is copied. You can create a Snowflake task and call it a 6 AM, to be safe you can modify the code to put a check that the ETL load is complete.

Comment: Hi Himanshu, what exactly are "p_src_obj_type" and 'p_tgt_obj_type', is this the entire view name that includes schema and database?

Comment: Getting an error message might have something to do with cur_main. SYNTAX ERROR: UNEXPECTED 'CUR_MAIN. (LINE 7) . also, I get a syntax error saying 'unexpected 'using' at line 7 position 14.

Comment: "v_sql :='CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ' || v_tgt_schema || i.target_table || ' AS SELECT * FROM ' ||         v_src_schema ||  i.source_table; "

 the above statement should be the following 

"v_sql :='CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ' || v_tgt_schema || v_tgt_table || ' AS SELECT * FROM ' ||         v_src_schema ||  v_src_table;  " right? 

we use 'v_tgt_table' instead of 'i.target_table'

Comment: I just corrected the formatting, the function defination starts from the following line " create or replace procedure DATA_TRANSFER_FF "

Comment: I run this as a whole right? I get a syntax error unexpected 'v_modified'. (LINE 22)

Comment: Hi the code for the function starts from "create or replace procedure DATA_TRANSFER_FF(p_src_db varchar2, p_tgt_db varchar2, p_src_schema varchar2, p_tgt_schema varchar2, p_src_obj_type varchar2, p_tgt_obj_type varchar2 )"    , i dont know why i was not able to format this on the forum.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a task to run the create table statement you gave in your question - though you would need to change it to “create or replace…”.

“ will the where clause impact my job?”: depends what you mean by impact. As the where clause will be part of the SQL being run it will obviously have an impact on your job. What are your specific concerns?

“ What happens when I insert a new column into my view?”: next time the table is re-created it will include all the columns in the view. What did you think would happen?

Comment: I thought adding new columns to the view would break the job, anyway, will try it and update how it goes